# Show page numbers in PDF using ITEXT

Tags: java, itext

We are using Itext for generating the PDF's in our web application. The PDF's are getting generated properly.

I need to show some copyright information in the footer along with page numbers. I need to show the copyright information on the left hand side at the bottom while the page numbers on the right hand side at the bottom.

I have gone through google and some articles, using them I could add footer at the bottom. But this footer displays only copyright at the right hand side in the bottom.

How can I add page numbers to this using Itext?

Below is the code I am using to generate the copyright information on the right hand side at the footer.

```
    static class HeaderFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {
    public void onEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("footer");
        BaseFont bf_times;
        try {
            bf_times = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, "Cp1252",
                    false);
            Font font = new Font(bf_times, 9);
            ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                    Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase("Copyright 2011",
                            font), (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2,
                    rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

As well below is the code which is used to show the page numbers. I am unable to combine both of these to show the page numbers and the copyright information at the same time.

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
    new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber()),
            font), (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2,
    rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: @jzd  At any given time I can display either Copyright or the page number. But not both at the same time. I need them on left and right side of the page at the footer.

Comment: how did you get writer.getPageNumber() when I am using my build fails I think u are using itext5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The showTextAligned function takes the following parameters.

```
public static void showTextAligned(PdfContentByte canvas,
                                   int alignment,
                                   Phrase phrase,
                                   float x,
                                   float y,
                                   float rotation)
```

In your example, you are setting the x-values for both items to the same value, so you may be writing one piece of text over the other.  Try adjusting your x-values to see if that helps.

Specifically, try setting the page number block of code so that is aligned with the right side of your footer Rectangle.

```
ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
    Element.ALIGN_RIGHT,
    new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber()),
            font),  rect.getRight(),
    rect.getBottom() - 18, 0);
```

Additionally, you can use the PDFStamper to add headers and footers after the fact to a PDF document.  Sometimes this can be a simpler approach.  The iText in Action book has several examples of this.  [Here's the code sample for one of them.](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=117)

Comment: OK. But how much I should change the x co-ordinate of the page number so that it shows up at the right hand side. For copyright I am using (rect.getLeft() + rect.getRight()) / 2. What should be the value/expression for the page number?

Comment: I used 550 and its coming at the proper place. But this is static value and is there any way specify it using the relative values for the PDF page as done for the copyright?

Comment: The Document parameter that you pass in has a method called getPageSize() which you can call to get a Rectangle that represents the page.

Additionally, you already have a bounding Rectangle for your footer right now.  If you want the copyright to be in the center, use the the average of the left and right side of the Rectangle, like you do now, but for the page number, set the x-value to the right side of the rectangle.  The Element.ALIGN_RIGHT should take care of making it so that the right edge of it lines up with the right side of your footer Rectangle.