# How to add page number in Header using itext in Java?

Tags: java, itext

I am unable to get the code to add the page number X of Y in Header of the page.

Comment: Refer this link, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717981/show-page-numbers-in-pdf-using-itext

Comment: Here I can get just page number But how can i get page number X of Y in Header? try to help me out?

Comment: it may help You, please  Refer this ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759909/how-to-add-total-page-number-on-every-page-with-itext

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by a **PdfTemplate**.
First, you attach a PdfPageEventHelper to PdfWriter

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, 
       new FileOutputStream("C:/path/to/pdf"));
writer.setPageEvent(new PageEventListener());
```

Then you define the class `PageEventListener` to extend `PdfPageEventHelper`.
In that class you override **onOpenDocument**, **onEndPage** and **onCloseDocument** methods and you can add page number in the form X of Y using a `PdfTemplate`.
Details with working code available [here](http://www.manning.com/lowagie2/SourceCodeiText.zip), in chapter05 directory, MovieCountries1.java
source.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class like below one

```
public class HeaderAndFooter extends PdfPageEventHelper {

public void onEndPage (PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    Rectangle rect = writer.getBoxSize("art");
    switch(writer.getPageNumber() % 2) {
    case 0:
       ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
               Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase("header"),
               rect.getBorderWidthRight(), rect.getBorderWidthTop(), 0);
        break;
    case 1:
        ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
                Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber())),
                300f, 62f, 0);
        break;
    }
   ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContent(),
            Element.ALIGN_CENTER, new Phrase(String.format("%d", writer.getPageNumber())),
            (2f + 4f) / 2, 2f - 18, 0);
}}
```

use below one in your generating pdf class

```
bytearrayoutputstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 60, 60, 120, 80);
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, bytearrayoutputstream );
        HeaderAndFooter event = new HeaderAndFooter();
        writer.setPageEvent(event);
        document.open();
```

change header alignment width according to ur document height and width